# Логика работы статических файлов

Tags: node.js

Ели я использую app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))) - то входе работы я страницу не могу изменить,использовать angular и метод гет для обмена данными,такой вид используется больше для шаблонного представления.
А лучше использовать сразу app.get()  - и по запросу отправлять мне нужные файлы с данными из базы данных?
Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: У Вас рендеринг на сервере, да?

Comment: Так точно, на сервере.

Comment: Если Вы про js файлы, то просто создайте несколько штук и для каждого отдельного вида грузите свой файл. Из базы берём только изменяемые данные типа текста статей и ссылок на изображения. Сами же файлы (картинки, js-файлы) хранятся в той же public.

Comment: Получается, что если я добавлю app.get("другой адрес") то статика все равно загрузит нужные мне файлы с папки паблик?